# Windows 11 slow internet when using wireless connection

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers

I have a fresh installation of Windows 11. However, wireless connection is not stable at all. Sometimes it reaches its full speed, sometimes becomes unbearably slow (a google search might take seconds to load).

Based on my assumptions, this should be a problem with the network adapter driver, because the network speed is fine when using usb tethering from an android phone connected to wifi. My wifi card is `rtl8852ae`.

Can anyone assist me to solve this problem, I will provide logs if requested

Comment: Considering you have two other similar questions at AskUbuntu and assuming your tests are being done in the same access point, perhaps you should check your router's settings. And that the same device seems to work fine in one OS but not in the other or that the Android phone also seems to work fine isn't as relevant as you might think. Please check the wireless encryption settings and assure the minimum WPA2-AES is being used, no WPA-WPA2 mixed mode and never the long time deprecated TKIP.

Comment: Its not the same pc. And for ubuntu it was fixed. This is just a conicidence that I have a similar problem with two computers

Comment: What I'm saying is it might not be a coincidence and what you think is fixed in Ubuntu might not be as good as it could be. DO NOT trust the default settings in ISP provided routers and/or old ones.

Comment: This is a driver issue, [this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/connection-issues-with-Realtek-RTL8852AE-WiFi-6-802-11ax/td-p/8157951) seems relevant.  While it’s for an HP laptop if you have a rtl8852ae it should be applicable. Download [Win11 Auto Installation Program (NetAdapterCx)](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) should download the correct driver.  Otherwise we need more information to find the driver on the Windows Update catalog.

Comment: [This](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/product-hits/item/high-speed-wireless-internet-access) suggests drivers that support **RTL8197F/RTL8198D/ RTL8198F** also support RTL8852A (which is also applicable to RTL8852AE). If after installing the June 30 2022 drivers that means something else NOT associated with Windows is the problem

Comment: I think I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [this link](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/connection-issues-with-Realtek-RTL8852AE-WiFi-6-802-11ax/td-p/8157951/page/2).

> Go to Device Manager
>
> 1.Realtek RTL 8852AE> Update Driver
>
> 2.Browse my computer for drivers> Let me pick from a list of availabe drivers on my computer
>
> 3.*Make sure the "show compatible hardware" is ticked
>
> 4.Choose the driver version 6001.0.10.304 and click next

I downgraded the driver to a version from 2021 and this seemed to fix the issue.